# Changing toolbar icons in a Matlab GUI GUIDE

Tags: matlab, user-interface, icons, toolbar, matlab-guide

I'm trying to put an icon in a pushbutton and I'm working with GUI GUIDE.

In `iconeditor` I try to import a file from Matlab icons path but it doesn't work.

Then I tried to program the button like this

```
function toolbar_OPT_ClickedCallback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to toolbar_Print (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

  % Use a MATLAB icon for the tool
  [X, map] = imread(fullfile(matlabroot,'toolbox','matlab','icons','matlabicon.gif'));

  % Convert indexed image and colormap to truecolor
  icon = ind2rgb(X,map);

  % Create a uipushtool in the toolbar
  hpt = uipushtool('CData',icon)
```

but its not working yet. Any sugestion?

Comment: is it possible to use .gif-files as icons? have you tried an .ico-file?

Comment: @LuciusDomitiusAhenobarbus I think yes because there are .gif and .png files there. Anyway I tried .ico also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as I see, you have to convert it and you are doing this...

BUT there is one parameter missing:

you need to add the handle of your toolbar as the first argument:

```
hpt = uipushtool(ht,'CData',icon,...
```

In your case you have to look for it within the handles-structure. Let me know, if you dont know how to get this!

**EDIT**

more advanced features for modifiying toolbars can be found at Yair's Blog "undocumented Matlab":

[figure-toolbar-components](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/figure-toolbar-components/)

Especially for your question, this could be interesting:

[figure-toolbar-customizations](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/figure-toolbar-components/)

I can strongly recommend Yair Altman's Blog!!

**EDIT#2**

when using GUIDE, your toolbar is created automatically and it seems to be difficult to get acces to its parameters. I couldnt test it completely, I just tried to identify the toolbar-handle by this:

```
hToolbarTogg = findall(gcf,'tag','uitoggletool1');
set(hToolbarTogg,'CData',icon)
```

You have to find out the what's the tag of your toolbar-toggle, which should be the same, when created with GUIDE...

Comment: I don't know because I don't want to create a new push button. I have have all my buttons created and just want to change the icon. Or any way to import icons

Comment: I'll check how to do this... ;-)

Comment: I tried to put the scripts in my toolbar_Callback but it does nothing. I don't know what is wrong because there are no errors and they don't explain how to do that in GUIs using GUIDE

Comment: Still not working :/
Also tried [this](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/7313) but didn't work too.

Comment: what error-message did you get? you could try to debug it and look for the name of your uitoggletool...

Comment: I don´t get any error but the icon is not replaced. The figure keeps showing the default push tools.